# Reledmac sidenotes collide

Tags: floats, reledmac, sidenotes

I am writing a document with Reledmac (which is necessary for me so cannot be changed). I make extensive use of \ledsidenote. However, when in one line the sidenote is quite long (and flows over to a following line), and I have a \ledsidenote in the following line too, there is a painful collission. How can I tell LaTeX to avoid this? (I know the manual tells these sidenotes are non-floating. I think they need to float.
Here is a MWE which shows the error:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\sidenotemargin{outer}
\leftnoteupfalse
\rightnoteupfalse
\setsidenotesep{ $|$ }

\begin{document}
 \beginnumbering
  \pstart
Lorem\ledsidenote{lorem}\ledsidenote{ipsum} \ledsidenote{dolor}\ledsidenote{sit amet}ipsum\ledsidenote{still no painful collission} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed dolor libero. Aenean\ledsidenote{but here the collission is} 
  \pend
 \endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: there is no solution except moving yourself the sidenote.  I don't see how reledmac could automatically determine the best place for  a side note. Maybe you can  change the font size for the sidenote.

Comment: @Maïeul: Thank you for your short reply. I don't know the interior of Reledmac, but what I want is easily done bij the marginpar-command, the marginnote-package or the sidenotes-package. But these don't work in a line-numbered environment, don't they?

Comment: it woul imply a new writing of the code for sidenote in reledmac.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it satisfies your requirement, but you can manually bump the new `\ledsidenote` down with a `~\\` prepended to the first of the overlapping sidenotes.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\sidenotemargin{outer}
\leftnoteupfalse
\rightnoteupfalse
\setsidenotesep{ $|$ }

\begin{document}
 \beginnumbering
  \pstart
Lorem\ledsidenote{lorem}\ledsidenote{ipsum} \ledsidenote{dolor}\ledsidenote{sit amet}ipsum\ledsidenote{still no painful collission} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed dolor libero. 
Aenean\ledsidenote{~\\but here the collission is} xyz\ledsidenote{ABC}
  \pend
 \endnumbering
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, like Maïeul, maintainer of the reledmac package, says: ‘there is no solution for this wish’.

When one tries to do something like this, one should not use reledmac.

Comment: OK, but which alternatives?